# CSS element overlay/overlap issue

Tags: css, html, overlay, overlap

I'm not CSS expert, but I believe that my task is very simple/basic for you experts.. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

**Update #1: HTML/CSS code found here: http://jsfiddle.net/x5buy/3**

Screenshots also:
This is the current accepted layout:
http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/5198/56133492.png

I need to add more items to the navigation, but the layout is corrupted, see:
http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/1058/21950608.png

**And that's the result I need to reach:**
http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/9349/45543510.png

Here it is the current responsible CSS code..

Header Main Container:
http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/7692/513201231541pm.png

Header Content:
http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/4977/513201222222pm.png

Navigation:
http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6426/513201222314pm.png

Comment: This is impossible to work with. Please make a fiddle @ http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/x5buy/3/

Comment: It's funny.. every time I see a question like this, I can't shake the feeling that your boos wants you to do something, and instead of learning how to do it yourself, you know taking the time to search the web, read blogs, you ask people here to do your job for you. Youa re not asking what you are doing wrong, or why your code doesn't work, you are just asking to make us do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make out what happens because it's not an exact replica of what you showed in the screen shots.

In any case, it seems pretty clear that your top menu is pushed down because the left `<div id="caption">` is pretty big. The way out is to make `<ul id="navigation">` absolutely positioned within `<div class="content">` (change the z-index if you need to).

Comment: At least it's demonstrating the same behavior, and in regard to z-index.. I'm neither UI developer nor CSS expert, so I don't know how to fix it. If you can help, please show your kindness and share the correct code.

Comment: It's exactly what @Daniel has written in his answer.

Comment: @Daniel posted appreciated code, but it didn't work correctly on live, additionally it seems that he has deleted his post, don't know why! Do you have any advice? Post updated with link to the website..

Comment: Checked the site, it looks like you did exactly what I've written ... so I don't see the problem anymore :)

Comment: It's working now, thank you Jack, and thanks for @Daniel as well. Since Daniel has deleted his post I've to choose your answer as the selected answer, reputation goes to you. Thanks